# Leer línea a línea un archivo txt c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una duda muy grande, debo leer línea a línea un archivo de texto que cuenta con el siguiente contenido (ejemplo):

```
01RG80500000000330000000022201811220100000002070000125801709                                                  
0000000000
020100000002780000000009V000010626565CARRENO SIMON 5273560000399578   00000001000009280000000000
```

Y necesito separar el contenido de  esas linea segun la informacion que tienen contenidas, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer lo. Ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no conoces, leer un archivo, extraer una porción de la línea? ¿Cuál es el criterio para separar los campos, por un espacio en blanco, por una cantidad fija de letras?

Comment: C# o c? Deja solo el lenguaje que necesitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leer linea a linea podrias usar

```
string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines("ruta");

foreach(string linea in lineas){
  //codigo
}
```

ahora para separar contenido si este va por tamaño fijo podrias usar

```
string val1 = linea.Substring(0,2);  //devuelve 01
string val2 = linea.Substring(3,5);  //devuelve RG805
string val3 = linea.Substring(8,10); //devuelve 0000000033
```

y asi el resto de los datos de cada linea

[Substring(Int32, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

El tema es que la forma de cortar vas a tener que ir variandola si es que no tienen todas el mismo largo o posicion de los datos